# How to find the hardware chipset information?

Tags: windows, motherboard

Is there any software, using which, I can detect the chipset versions/name (like Audio ALC889, Network 8111E, etc). I want to detect these chipsets of my hardware.

I tried software CPUID, but it's not providing such information.

What I really need is this. Check the website http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1155/P8H67M_PRO/#specifications

- Audio is Realtek® ALC 892
- LAN is Realtek® 8111E

I want to see this information from my system/BIOS or any tool.

Comment: Never tried it but maybe you can determine it using the vendor ID in the bios...http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-find-unknown-device-drivers-by-their-vendor-device-id/

Answer (score 6):

[Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy) can do this, and it also has a Portable Edition available.

### Summary

[image]

### Motherboard

[image]

### Network

[image]

Comment: Its showing me same Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller for Network, whats its chipset number? 8111B, 8111C or 8111E? I want that exact info

Comment: @coure2011: What do you need it for? You can't determine it automatically until after you installed the drivers, that's because you need to search the hardware ID of Device Manager on Google. It's not necessary to know that to install the drivers...

Answer (score 6):

I typically discover chipsets by going to the Device Manager, right clicking on the appropriate device and going to *Properties*.

On the *Details* tab, sift through the drop down options for anything telling. If it's not obvious there, I take the ID from *Hardware Ids* and google them.

Comment: That's what I suggested [here](http://superuser.com/questions/328366/how-to-detect-hardware-chipset/328375#comment-355758), but that's not what is currently being asked. The question is a bit vague...

Comment: `on the appropriate device` what is appropriate device for laptop chipset? no one. The answer is not useful

Comment: @Suncatcher The original question listed multiple devices, therefore "the appropriate device"

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Intel chipset, this would apply:

*[Intel Chipset Identification Software](http://www.intel.com/support/chipsets/inf/sb/CS-009266.htm)*

Comment: offcourse I came here after searching on google, its the first link that comes in google search with keyword "chipset detection". Dont provide information like this..

Comment: @coure2011: That's what your title asked, it identifies the Motherboard Chipset.

Comment: @coure2011 If you've found and tried something and it didn't work, mention it in the question so we don't waste time suggesting things you've already discounted.

Comment: Must warn - it does not appear to work on the latest version of Windows 10. May need to find another method...

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [SIW](http://www.gtopala.com) (System Information for Windows):

> SIW is an advanced System Information for Windows tool that analyzes your computer and gathers detailed information about system properties and settings and displays it in an extremely comprehensible manner.
>
> The System Information is divided into few major categories:
>
> - Software Information: Operating System, Software Licenses (Product Keys / Serial Numbers / CD Key), Installed Software and Hotfixes, Processes, Services, Users, Open Files, System Uptime, Installed Codecs, Passwords Recovery, Server Configuration.
>
>   - Hardware Information: Motherboard, CPU, Sensors, BIOS, **chipset**, PCI/AGP, USB and ISA/PnP Devices, Memory, Video Card, Monitor, Disk Drives, CD/DVD Devices, SCSI Devices, S.M.A.R.T., Ports, Printers.
>   - Network Information: Network Cards, Network Shares, currently active Network Connections, Open Ports.
>   - Network Tools: MAC Address Changer, Neighborhood Scan, Ping, Trace, Statistics, Broadband Speed Test
>   - Miscellaneous Tools: Eureka! (Reveal lost passwords hidden behind asterisks), Monitor Test, Shutdown / Restart.
>   - Real-time monitors: CPU, Memory, Page File usage and Network Traffic.

[image]