# What RAM do I need to get?

Tags: laptop, memory, sony-vaio

I can't work out what RAM I need. I'm not even sure what laptop I have! All I know is:

- It's a Sony VIAO, and there is a small marking "VPCF11JOE" just below the screen.
- The installed memory is 6GB
- It has an Intel i5 64 bit 2.4GHz M520 processor running Windows 7
- It has not been modified since it was bought new.

I'm thinking of upgrading the RAM but I don't know what my options are. I don't want to spend more than about $100. Any help/suggestions would be hugely appreciated!

- Will I need to replace the RAM that's in there?
- Or can I just buy an extra memory stick?
- What kind of RAM do I need to buy?

Thanks!

Comment: Need a model number, and 6GB should be enough for about anything a laptop should do.

Comment: Thanks - but I defo need more RAM. I've minimised background processes etc. Also I want to increase file cache size, and my system is low on memory as it is, I had to increase virtual memory. How would I find the model number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most probably your **Chipset: Mobile Intel® PM55 Express**

```
Installed Memory : 6GB (4GB+2GB)
Memory Type/Speed : DDR3/1333MHz
Max. Memory : 8GB
```

So you will need to swap the 2GB Stick for a 4GB Stick with, ideally, same specs as the other stick.

**In Addition:** A question has been answered with some tips/tools that will help you [here](https://superuser.com/questions/328366/how-to-find-the-hardware-chipset-information). 
The Tool is called [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy) and will give you exact details on your hardware.

Comment: Thank you! I will see if I can get at the RAM to have a look at it.